# Setup and deployment with input dialog in c#.net

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I created one windows service and want a input dialog in its setup to take two parameters from user at the time of installation and if user enter parameters then only `Next` button should available.

Also want to fetch these parameters value to use them.

I have also added a ProjectInstaller on my service and added below code on `ProjectInstaller.cs` class, but its not working.

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
  base.Install(stateSaver);
  DBConfigurationClass objDBConfigurationClass = new DBConfigurationClass();

  objDBConfigurationClass.SUserName = Context.Parameters["UserName"];
  objDBConfigurationClass.SLic = Context.Parameters["LicenseKey"]; 
}

public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
{
base.Commit(savedState);
}

public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
{
base.Rollback(savedState);
}

public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
base.Uninstall(savedState);
}
```